# Convert microphone recording to string in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

**Background info**
I am trying to convert a microphone recording to a string.

So far I have been following this sample from MSDN website to create a program that allows me to record with the microphone and play it back.  Below is the link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442302%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Sadly, I have not found any way how I can convert recording to string.

**Question** How do I convert the microphone recording to string?

I have tried to use Speech Recognition Engine but unfortunately the namespace **`System.Speech`** cannot be used in Windows Phone 8 sdk.

Comment: what do you mean, "string". you want to do voice recognition of someone saying the words "hello, world", producing a string with the literal characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, etc....? Or do you want a string that contains the binary "garbage" of the audio recording?

Comment: @MarcB By string I mean the words "Hello world" with literal charecters.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Windows.Phone.Speech](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.speech.recognition.aspx) for speech recognition, not System.Speech.  An overview is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206958(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to mention, but I want to avoid using Windows.Phone.Speech because of it's limitation on how long you can record speech.